# Do actions when rotate the screen

Tags: objective-c, rotation, orientation, action

when i rotate the screen i want to do some actions.
I'm currently using this method but it's not working.

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"rotated!");
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you register that method for the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`? Did you call `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`?

Comment: @MartinR +1 - also, are you really trying to use the actual orientation of the device? Or only the screen orientation? In the latter case, you should use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` in your `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Soved with:
(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOri‌​entation